# AsyncTask Fatal Error #1

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

While run this code Async fatal error occurs.

I am making an application which will control computer on remote distance like Team viewer.

```
package pk.edu.cust.fyp.nobeen.sameer.umair.pccontroller;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button connectBtn;
    EditText ipAddressEditTxt;
    String ipAddress;
    int port=4444;
    boolean connectionResult = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        ipAddressEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipEditText);
        ipAddress = ipAddressEditTxt.getText().toString();


        connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {             
                ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection();
              clientConnection.execute(ipAddress);
              if(connectionResult == true) {

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
     class ClientConnection extends AsyncTask <String,String,String>
    {
        Socket socket;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        Context context;
        String TAG ="Client Connection";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"doInBackground run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {

                socket = new Socket(params.toString(), port);

                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection is succesfully "+dataInputStream.readUTF(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(socket.isConnected())
                {
                    connectionResult=true;
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception occur: "+ex,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.e(TAG,ex.toString());
                connectionResult = false;
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
          super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OnPost"+connectionResult,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Same error question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558855/fatal-exception-asynctask-1-android

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual logcat

Answer (score -1):

**Issue:** you are showing Toast in background which not run UI thread. Remove both Toast messages from doInBackground() method

If you wanna show toasts, show them in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods as those are called in UI thread but doInBackground() is being called in separate thread.

Comment: Ali, I proposed an edit to your faulty answer and you reviewed it and rejected it rather than accepting a well edited answer.   You previously answered "ou are showing Toast in background which run UI thread" and that was wrong because in background it is not running on UI thread.  Be grateful people try to help you rather than rejecting suggestions for no reason.

Comment: Next time proofread your answer if you don't want people to edit it.

Comment: before you suggest the edit ,answer was edited. and still you wanted your suggestion accepted? no issue with negative voting but I'm not going to approve something which was not helpful in anyway.

Comment: That's not true because my suggestion showed before your edit and the one rejecting the edit suggestion was you.  Just move on dude.